# Unable to click custom back button on mobile version in WooCommerce

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, mobile, woocommerce

In Woocommerce I have a custom back button, but when I click on it in Mobile Version, it doesn't work.

The button link to the image but not the back functionality.

Here's my code:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_before_single_product_summary_button', 5);

function woocommerce_before_single_product_summary_button() {
     echo ' <button class="backbutton" type="button" onclick="history.back();"> Back </button> ';
}
```

It works on desktop version but not on mobile version.

How can I make it work either on mobile and desktop versions?

Answer (score 1):

Inside your hooked function, I have replaced your `<button>` by `<a>` including a jQuery script that will detect when this button is clicked and will trigger a similar event `history.go(-1);` that should work everywhere, including mobile touch devices.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_before_single_product_summary_button', 5);
function woocommerce_before_single_product_summary_button() {
    echo ' <a href="#" class="back-button button"> '. __('Back').' </a> ';
    ?>
        <script>
            (function($) {
                $('a.back-button').click(function(e){
                    e.preventDefault();
                    history.go(-1);
                });
            })(jQuery);
        </script>
    <?php
}
```

This code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme).

This should work (tested on android and safari desktop, but not on iOS)…

Comment: Thanks LoicTheAztec

Comment: @AftabHusain did you tested this on iOS ?